# How many different races (castes) were created by Brahma or God ? Where can I get hierarchical order of superior to inferior races (castes)?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, caste-system

Are there only only four types of races created by Brahma namely - Brahman , Kshatriya , Vaishya or Shudras ?

Or Even amongst the above four races separate sub-races were created ?

Like even among Brahmin caste not all Brahmin sub-caste marry with each other.
Like I have heard that Kanyakubja Brahmin women marry with KanyaKubja Brahmin men only.
While KanyaKubja Brahmin men can marry women of other Brahmin sub-caste ? (So, even here Pratilom and Anulom marriage can exist)

It indicates that there are different sub-caste created by Brahma with some sub-caste superior to others.

Where can I get hierarchical order of superior to inferior races (caste) ?

Comment: The vedas speak of only 4 varnas.